# sort dataframe by position in group then by that group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=list('aaaaabbbbccc'),
        B=range(12)
    ))

print(df)

    A   B
0   a   0
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   a   4
5   b   5
6   b   6
7   b   7
8   b   8
9   c   9
10  c  10
11  c  11
```

I want to sort the dataframe such if I grouped by column `'A'` I'd pull the first position from each group, then cycle back and get the second position from each group if any are remaining.  So on and so forth.

I'd expect results tot look like this

```
    A   B
0   a   0
5   b   5
9   c   9
1   a   1
6   b   6
10  c  10
2   a   2
7   b   7
11  c  11
3   a   3
8   b   8
4   a   4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count values in `groups` first, then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `Series` `cum`:

```
cum = df.groupby('A')['B'].cumcount().sort_values()
print (cum)
0     0
5     0
9     0
1     1
6     1
10    1
2     2
7     2
11    2
3     3
8     3
4     4
dtype: int64

print (df.reindex(cum.index))
    A   B
0   a   0
5   b   5
9   c   9
1   a   1
6   b   6
10  c  10
2   a   2
7   b   7
11  c  11
3   a   3
8   b   8
4   a   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a NumPy approach -

```
def approach1(g, v):
    # Inputs : 1D arrays of groupby and value columns
    id_arr2 = np.ones(v.size,dtype=int)
    sf = np.flatnonzero(g[1:] != g[:-1])+1
    id_arr2[sf[0]] = -sf[0]+1
    id_arr2[sf[1:]] = sf[:-1] - sf[1:]+1
    return id_arr2.cumsum().argsort(kind='mergesort')
```

Sample run -

```
In [246]: df
Out[246]: 
    A   B
0   a   0
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   a   3
4   a   4
5   b   5
6   b   6
7   b   7
8   b   8
9   c   9
10  c  10
11  c  11

In [247]: df.iloc[approach1(df.A.values, df.B.values)]
Out[247]: 
    A   B
0   a   0
5   b   5
9   c   9
1   a   1
6   b   6
10  c  10
2   a   2
7   b   7
11  c  11
3   a   3
8   b   8
4   a   4
```

Or using `df.reindex` from [`@jezrael's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41547677/3293881) :

```
df.reindex(approach1(df.A.values, df.B.values))
```